# Forcefully terminating a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am creating a thread in python which executes a method situated in some other module.
I am also reading an input from GUI. If a certain button is pressed in GUI, I want to stop execution of my thread.

Generally, if method called in thread ends executing, the thread will also terminate with method. But, in my case, the method is like an infinite loop which will keep executing as long as main program is running. I have tried `sys.exit()` along with a flag to terminate method as shown in pseudo code below. But, this does not close the thread.

For my application using multi-processing instead of multi-threading is not an option.

```
# Pseudo code for method running in the thread

# 'flag_status' is not part of method, but declared in the same module

flag_status = True

def method():
    if flag_staus:
         # execute method (go in loop)
    else: 
         # flag status is changed in some other module based on input from GUI.
         sys.exit()
```

Can someone please tell me how can I terminate this thread externally (possibly forcefully)?